# Unable to change asset links in theme after wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am helping a friend who moved a wordpress installation from a temporary URL to the real one. Right now there are two folders with almost identical wordpress installations, *wpsitename* and *sitename*. Now some URLs still point to assets in the old *wpsitename* folder. The URLs have been changed with a URL replace plugin, which worked for all existing URLs except for ones in theme related rows in the wp_options table. There seems to be about 20 such URLs remaining there. I tried manually changing all of the URLs which apparently reset or broke the theme so that it would show the original demo version of the theme and content, this also happened when i tried changing only one URL.

The theme is buildup pro and the *option_name* in the *wp_options* table is also buildup_pro. I also tried looking for settings in the theme related to any assets/images, but did not find any.

Do you have any ideas of how to repair this issue or find any clues to how to do it? I also wonder why the theme would break if one URL is changed in it's settings... I also wonder if this could be an issue with the theme itself or if it is a wordpress migration issue.

Here is also a small sample of the first part of the db entry with the urls:

```
a:289:{s:4:"logo";s:64:"http://wp.sitename.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/sitename_logo-2.png";s:10:"logoheight";s:2:"70";s:14:"hide_titledesc";s:1:"1";s:9:"boxlayout";b:0;s:9:"headstick";b:0;s:12:"headersocial";s:262:"[social_area] [social icon="facebook" link="https://fi-fi.facebook.com/sitename/"]...
```

Thank you for even the smallest hint that could lead me in the right direction!

Comment: it's serialized array. and just changing something may brack all saved data. try to search for changing data from serialized array will provide you a lot of examples how to convert/change url's

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan, thanks, the keyword "serialized" was what i needed to find relevant info, if you want to write an answer based on that I will accept that as the answer. Otherwise I will answer the question with how the problem was solved, if anyone else finds this question later on.

Comment: glad to help. answer yourself